# saner listings monospace font size relative to surrounding text size

Tags: fonts, xetex, listings, fontsize

Is it possible to make listings and especially inline listings font size to be saner? It appears that the font size is chosen so that capital letters of the monospace font are full height of a line. It would be nice if the font size was chosen so that lowercase letters of the monospace font match the surrounding text's font's lowercase letters in height. Is this doable?

Comment: Using `\setmonofont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{DejaVu Sans Mono}` actually looks the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\setmonofont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{DejaVu Sans Mono}` (or `MatchLowercase`) actually solves the problem.